# Updating URL for parsing XML in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to figure out how to update an URL that I am using to parse the XML (using `simplexml_load_file()`).

There is a `button` that has a `$productid` that is assigned to it by the user when they add their shortcode `[show_cart_button productid=#]`.

```
//code for the button input that gets called    

function print_add_cart_button($productid, $atts = array()) {
   //some other form code for the button

   $replacement .= '<input type="hidden" name"cart_product" value"' . $productid . '"/>';
  return $replacement;
}
```

This is the `function` I am using to display and call the product information:

```
function show_shopping_cart_handler($atts) {
   if (isset($_POST['cart_product'])) {
      $id = "&PRODUCTID=" . $_POST['cart_product'];
    // uses the input name from the button
   }

   $url = "https://secure.bmtmicro.com/cart?CID=2/WP" . $id;
   
   $xml = simplexml_load_file($url) or die("error.");

   foreach ($xml->producttable->row as $product) {
      $output .= '<span>' . $product->productname . '</span>';
   }

   return $output;
}
```

The way the URL will work properly is to have a `&PRODUCTID=(product#)` added to the end of the URL. For example, if you click two different buttons, the URL should look like this: `https://secure.bmtmicro.com/cart?CID=2/WP&PRODUCTID=1&PRODUCTID=2` (obviously 1 and 2 will need to display the buttons `$productid` number).

As you should be able to see from my code above, every time a `button` gets clicked, it just rewrites the URL and displays that one product, instead of adding a new one to the list. I tried to set the `simplexml_load_file()` into a `foreach()`, but that would not display any products when the button was clicked. Does anyone know a way I could get that URL to update/work properly?

Answer (score 0):

Everytime

```
 if (isset($_POST['cart_product'])) {
      $id = "&PRODUCTID=" . $_POST['cart_product'];
    // uses the input name from the button
   }
```

Is called, it's overwriting $id. You need to get any existing values for the url.

You'll have to get all of the current values ($_GET['cart_productions']), throw them into an array, grab the new post, add it to the array and add all of them to them the url using http_build_query().